# What is the vcslog table in JediVCS used for?

Tags: version-control, jedi

Just wondering what the vcslog table is used for in JediVCS.

I received some consistancy errors on this table (during my backup procedure these errors were flagged by the database backend) and there is a chance that after repair some data went missing.

If the table is just acting as a log then this should be ok.

Some other info:

- Was going to ask this quesion on the JediVCS news group but it appears to 
  be down
- I do have recent backups that I could restore but would rather not as it 
  means finding and re-committing any intervening work.
- I diffed all other tables and their data between the pre-fix and post-fix 
  versions of the VCS and they all match.
- I tried to diff the vcslog table but the tool I have crashed as the table 
  has millions of records. (I think the tool ran out of memory doing the 
  diff)

Any info appreciated.

Peter Mayes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up mailing the active JediVCS admin staff directly.

Thanks go to them for their prompt and helpul advice.

Basically the vcslog table holds information relating to actions taken by a user. As such its data is entirely optional, but recommended.

The least useful records are marked as type=g in the database. (This logs a 'get' operation by a user).

After deleting these records directly in the database the vcslog table reduced in size by 97%. (I suspect the large number of 'get' logs is due to our nighly autobuilds).

The database has been stable since the clear. (Some six weeks ago)

Here are some other topics in the JediVCS help manual I was pointed at.
Just in case they prove helpful to someone. These detail the logging behaviour inside the JediVCS client:

- "Project history"
- "Application server options"
- "Write VCS log"